# jquery plugin video background too large

Tags: jquery, video, background, scale

I'm making a web page with a HD video that's been compressed as my video background, my problem is that it works, but every time I use it there's a slight amount of horizontal scroll and I wondered if there was any way of properly scaling the video in the jquery code here:

--

```
$('body').videoBG({
    position:"fixed",
    zIndex:-1,
    mp4:'assets/clouds.mp4',
    ogv:'assets/christmas_snow.ogv',
    webm:'assets/clouds.webm',
    poster:'assets/clouds.jpg',
    opacity:1,
    fullscreen: true, 
});
```

If I take fullscreen off, then the video becomes more square like and the video is cropped and blurry showing only a portion enlarged to a massive amount to fill the screen (but not quite enough to fill all of it)

Comment: it may the the `body` `width` and `height` that is wrong, or margins. Can you post more more or a demo?

Comment: Same problems, any solution?